# Multiple lines in file appearing as only one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save some variables to a file on separate lines.

My code looks like this:

```
def saveall(sname, senemyname, scheckpoint,):
    file = open("savefile.sav", "w")
    file.writelines([sname, senemyname, scheckpoint])
    file.close()
```

If I put `saveall("John","Steve","Crossroads")` in my code, I want it to make a file called savefile.sav, containing:

```
John

Steve

Crossroads
```

However, when I run the program, savefile.sav contains:

`JohnSteveCrossroads`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some things to remember in Python: readlines() doesn't strip the newline char, while writelines() doesn't append the newline char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writelines` doesn't add separators between the lines, so you have to add them yourself:

```
def saveall(sname, senemyname, scheckpoint,):
    file = open("savefile.sav", "w")
    file.writelines((line + '\n' for line in [sname, senemyname, scheckpoint]))
    file.close()

saveall("John","Steve","Crossroads")
```

File content:

```
John 
Steve 
Crossroads
```

Answer (score 3):

`writelines` expects each string to be newline terminated. So you need:

```
file.writelines([sname + '\n', senemyname + '\n', scheckpoint + '\n'])
```

From [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines):

> **`writelines`**(*lines*)
>
> Write a list of lines to the stream. Line separators are not added, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a line separator at the end.

But usually it's more idiomatic to do `file.write('\n'.join([sname, senemyname, scheckpoint))`. Note that that doesn't add the file newline.

You should also be using contexts for files, because if an exception is raised you may not close your file:

```
with open('savefile.sav', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([sname, senemyname, scheckpoint]))
```